# Format the text after 4 characters (ABCD-EFGH-IJKL) but allow editing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to format and allow edit formated string in input with jquery, but I cannot achieve editing formated string correctly. Actually when user make mistake when typing code into input and want to correct it, it jump user to the end of the chain, because it forced formate it when user delete a char. How can i edit it, to let user correct his mistake but still format the chain?

What user type: 8F489T4R8T5O7S8E

What user see:  8F48-9T4R-8T5O-7S8E

But when user want to correct O to 0, it make result like this 8F48-9T4R-8T57-S8E0, because it will forced reformat the string immediately and put the 0 to the end of the chain.

```js
    $("input[name=login-access-token]").keyup(function(event){
        var input = $(this).val();
        input = input.replace(/[\W\s\._\-]+/g, '');
        var split = 4;
        var chunk = [];
         
        for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i += split) {
            split = 4;
            chunk.push( input.substr( i, split ) );
        }
        $(this).val(function() {
            var out = chunk.join("-").toUpperCase();
            
            if(out.length == 4 && event.keyCode != 8){
                    out += "-";
            }
            
            if(out.length == 9 && event.keyCode != 8 ){
                    out += "-";
            }
            
            return out;
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="login-access-token" placeholder="Code" />
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in .keyup? i tried keydown but same result.. what is your advices?

Comment: blur or focusout event solves the problem. but dont know it meet your requirement

Comment: @Jake thanks for advice, but blur and focusout works only if user click outside the div/input, that means value in input will not be formated until user left the input.

Comment: try to keep the displayed text and the actual field value decoupled.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues how you mean it please?

Comment: I added code snippet here, i hope my problem is now more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added new if condition.

```
    $("input[name=login-access-token]").keyup(function(event){
     if (event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46) { //New conditions added
        var input = $(this).val();
        input = input.replace(/[\W\s\._\-]+/g, '');
        var split = 4;
        var chunk = [];
         
        for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i += split) {
            split = 4;
            chunk.push( input.substr( i, split ) );
        }
        $(this).val(function() {
            var out = chunk.join("-").toUpperCase();
            
            if(out.length == 4 && event.keyCode != 8){
                    out += "-";
            }
            
            if(out.length == 9 && event.keyCode != 8 ){
                    out += "-";
            }
            
            return out;
        });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for advice! But this will works only on PC when using keyboard, i want to make it work also in tablet or mobile device if user remove char and place correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good use case for the plugin [jquery-inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).

Take a look at the documentation, there are plenty of options.

If you combine it with the CSS property [`text-transform: uppercase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform), you get most of your desired behavior in a one-liner javascript (plus workable copy/paste and disabling non-alpha characters).

```js
$("input[name=login-access-token]").inputmask()
```

```css
input {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="login-access-token" placeholder="Code" data-inputmask="'mask': '****-****-****-****'"/>
```

Comment: I am trying to do it without any plugin, just pure js or jquery, but thanks!

Comment: I understand. But if you are already loading the huge jquery into your page, you should honestly consider just using this 6k stars plugin, and go spend your effort into making your webpage awesome. If you were not using jquery at all, I'd be all with you.